# Best region for server to serve US

Tags: google-compute-engine, hosting, mongodb, latency

I want to create a MongoDB Atlas instance and Google Cloud instance to serve the US region. Is there a rule of thumb which region (east, center, south) or city that is the best choice to serve entire US with lowest latency?

Answer (score 2):

Lowest latency for who? Those on the west coast? Those on the east coast? No matter which region you select one will wait longer than the other.

In general, you will not find an even traffic distribution across the US. Therefore, select the region closest to your largest customer concentration. Analytics will help answer your question.